# Starting a program in batch file without stealing focus

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I know how to do this in C++, C#, etc, but I've got a simple BAT file that does a couple operations on a file, opens it in Notepad++, and proceeds to the next file. Because I want to wait for it to finish running on 2 to 20 files, I want it to run in the background until it's finished.

Here's my line to open the file in Notepad++:

```
start "" /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%filepath%"
```

Is it possible to `START` a program so that it runs without stealing focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a general solution, but for your specific requirement (notepad++) you could try command line option of `notepad++.exe -systemtray`
[from notepad cmd line spec:](http://notepad.cwaniak.info/documentation/notepad-user-manual/command-line.html)

> -systemtray
>   Start Notepad++ minimised in the system tray, aka notification area

*(There is an option to start program minified `start /min`, but n++ does not honor it... it works with regular notepad, though)*

Comment: Accepted because /MIN is technically what I was looking for, AND for noticing that Notepad++ ignores that switch. Was driving me crazy. I couldn't get `-systemtray` to work like I wanted, so instead I built a list while iterating and called Notepad++ at the end of the loop with a list of files.